# Is there a way to run a Deep Learning model locally with the data on AWS S3?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, amazon-s3, deep-learning, neural-network

I am trying to implement a Neutral Network using Tensorflow with the dataset categorized into different folders (Each folders represent each class). I would like to know if there's a way to use the data from S3 and run the Deep Learning model in the local machine.

I have all the files on S3 but am unable to bring it to the local machine.

P.S I'm using Python version 3.5

Answer (score 1):

As of now, no deep learning framework supports fetching data from s3 and train, maybe because of s3 pricing.

However you can mount S3 on your local system

- S3-Fuse - https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse
- S3Fs - https://fs-s3fs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Please not, for every read / write you will be billed according to aws s3 pricing, https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow supports this (but I think not in the nightly builds), see [documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/community/en/docs/deploy/s3.md).
Assuming you have configured the credentials as described (e.g. $HOME/.aws/credentials or with environment variables), you have to use URLs with s3 as protocol like

```
s3://mybucket/some/path/words.tsv
```

If you read or write files in your own code, be sure not to use any python IO but Tensorflow's [tf.io.gfile.GFile](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/gfile/GFile). Similar, to list directories use e.g. [tf.io.gfile.walk](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/gfile/walk?hl=ro) or [tf.io.gfile.listdir](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/gfile/listdir?hl=ro)

From the environment variables in the documentation, we only set `AWS_REGION`, but in addition the following ones are useful to control logging and avoid timeouts:

```
export AWS_LOG_LEVEL=3
export S3_REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MSEC=600000
```

Still, reading training data from s3 is usually only a good idea if you run your training on AWS. For running locally, it is usually better to copy the data to your local drive, e.g. with [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/?nc1=h_ls)'s [sync](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) command.